# Tutorial or book about MVC 4 and jQuery

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-mobile, asp.net-mvc-4

I have been looking for many days now for an advanced tutorial or book on integrating MVC 4 and jQuery Mobile(Visual studio 2012). I am into building "mobile-only" sites (not desktop sites which are also mobile friendly but mobile-only sites from the ground).

Most of the tutorials and books I have found talk about Asp.net MVC4 in general and devote only one or 2 chapters on mobile-only new features in MVC 4 (basically they just mention new project template "Mobile Application" in the Visual Studio 2012 but they don't got in-depth about integrating jQuery mobile and MVC 4).

Other tutorials just explain the "basics" of mvc 4 and jquery mobile ( hello-world-like tutorials). I'm looking for something more advanced and professional tutorial or book mainly devoted on **mvc 4** **and** **jquery mobile** for mobile-only sites where one can more efficiently learn to use the power of the 2 worlds: mvc 4 and jquery mobile

Answer (score 0):

You will get some practical examples in codeproject.

[Jquery and MVC 4](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/413099/HTML5-jQuery-Mobile-and-ASP-NET-MVC-4-Using-the-Vi)

Comment: thank i'll have a look at this link